# JMSI18nRoutingBundle Detect preferred language

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

Is there a way to detect the user's locale for the strategy "prefix_except_default"?

eg

default locale: en

if I go on www.example.com and the user's locale is set to "fr" it redirects me to www.example.com/fr

Just as with "prefix", only that the locale default route will have the www.example.com rather than www.example.com/en

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
<ul id="language-selector">
    {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'homepage' %}            
        <li><a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "fr"}) }}">FR</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "en"}) }}">EN</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">FR</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">EN</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Thank you @xiidea for his explanation ;)

Comment: It will through error, like you know from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23457456/1289495) :)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean `_locale` parameter or `preferredLocale` of the browser?
If the `_locale` is set, the redirection should be done automatically.
For checking the `preferredLocale` of the browser you can use following line:

```
$request->getPreferredLanguage();
```

or in Twig:

```
app.request.preferredLocale
```