# JMSi18nRoutingBundle language selector

Tags: symfony, routes, translation

I have implemented the following language switcher:

```
<ul id="language-selector">
    {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) == '/' %}
        <li><a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "es"}) }}">ES</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "en"}) }}">EN</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "it"}) }}">IT</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'es'})) }}">ES</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">EN</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'it'})) }}">IT</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

I'm using [JMSi18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) for translating the urls. It works fine but when it renders a view which has a parameter in the url, the following error appears:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory
parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route
"es__RG__myapp_mybundle_myaction_edit".") in
MyAppMyBundle:Default:includes/myView.html.twig at line 21.
```

Comment: Please see my answer, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following condition to check for homepage

> {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'homepage' %}

instead of

> {% if path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) == '/' %}

### **Explanation:**

When you are accessing an URL which required parameter(s), your code in if statement `path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'))` generates the error. As your home page route is defined as **`homepage`**, only checking the `_route` attribute will be enough to determine that you are accessing the homepage.

Happy coding!!

Comment: @benatespina: Your question is little bit self contradictory!! if you want disable the locale on homepage, then why are you passing `{"_locale": "es"}` these values while creating URLs? And after setting `{ i18n: false }` option why are you expecting locale to change?

Comment: @benatespina: What you wants is doable using **cookie**, as done in your website.